Problems playing G.726 audio with FFplay or when converted via FFmpeg
I found an old audio file — created by a Panasonic web-cam some 15 years ago — in G.726 format. The camera produced two separate streams: MP4 video and G726 audio.
I tried playing it with FFplay and got:
audio-G726-32-1: Invalid data found when processing input

This seems to indicate file-corruption, which is entirely possible, given the file's age — it was recorded two PCs ago.
But then I did the following test:

Used FFmpeg to convert a perfectly valid MP3 file to G.726 format:
ffmpeg -f mulaw -i 2223-01.mp3 -ar 8000 -f g726 /tmp/2223-01.g726


Tried playing the result:
ffplay /tmp/2223-01.g726



This yielded the same "Invalid data" error. Is there a rot in FFmpeg's G.726 code? Any other explanations?

FFmpeg and FFplay are sensitive to file extensions. Try: ffplay -f g726 /tmp/2223-01.g726. (I don't know why FFplay doesn't recognize .g726 file extension).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2509191/7986904

@JayCravens, so the G726-support was broken in FFMpeg 14 years ago -- and still is... How sad -- why hasn't anyone filed a ticket with the developers? I'll try to make a FreeBSD of the g72x++ meanwhile...

@MikhailT. It's more of a unused factor. There is a library for it, but it's never usually with video, so no one's bothered with it. Lack of demand. That's Panasonic having a weird obsession with telecom audio formats on early camcorder devices.  I've seen this a few times only, in about that long.  First time was 16 years ago, and I was still a windows user back then.

I compiled that code -- linking it against the latest spandsp instead of the bundled copy -- but the sox command-line suggested on the mailing list does not work -- the -w and the -s options are no longer recognized. Using -r 8000 -c 1 -t raw -e signed -b 32 seems to have worked, but there is a strong pervasive hum...

@Rotem, with the -f g726 ffplay does play the just-generated file, but the sound is not even remotely recognizable. Not just "lower quality" -- utter noise...

I converted a stereo MP3 file by adding -ac 1: ffmpeg -y -i music.mp3 -ar 8000 -ac 1 -f g726 test.g726. It sounds fine to me...
